# How to access kernel header files?

Tags: linux, kernel, header-file

I'm a student working with the Linux kernel, and was wondering how to access methods and macros in the kernel header files from outside the kernel in an OS. I apologize if this is an ignorant question, Linux is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Access them to do what?

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_2.html

Comment: You either install the complete kernel source (with the headers), or you install a package from your distro that only contains the kernel headers. Then you can access them in any way you want, on the file system, as files. Was that the question?

Comment: @dirkt, you answered my question. Thank you guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command to install linux headers fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19898/command-to-install-linux-headers-fails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either install the complete kernel source (with the headers), or you install a package from your distro that only contains the kernel headers. Then you can access them in any way you want, on the file system, as files.